# expandable listview not loading after runOnUiThread

Tags: android, multithreading, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-runonuithread

i am trying to bind data on a expandable listview. A new thread has been called because of too much load on the main thread during populate a map from database.

> MY problem is, expandable list view is not showing after new thread
>   execution but if i set a break point on the adapter initialization ,
>   it working fine..i tried notifyDataSetChanged() but no luck

[image]

**Activity**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }
         selectedvalue = extras.getString("selected_data");
        if (selectedvalue != null) {
            TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2SelectedData);
            textView.setText(selectedvalue);
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
        }
        fillData();
        ExpandableListView expandableListview =(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.ExpandablelistSelectedData);
        ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter=new CustomAdapterExpandableList(this,manufacturerUnique,relatedMedicine);
        expandableListview.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    }
    public void fillData(){
        manufacturerUnique=new ArrayList<>();
        relatedMedList=new ArrayList<>();
        relatedMedicine=new HashMap<>();
        dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait","Loading...", false);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    manufacturerUnique=dbHelper.getManfacturerNameListusingBrandOrGenericName(selectedvalue);
                    System.out.println("manufacturerUnique size"+manufacturerUnique.size());
                    for(int i=0;i<manufacturerUnique.size();i++){
                        relatedMedicine.put(manufacturerUnique.get(i),dbHelper.getBrandNameUsingSelectedItemAndmanfacturerName(selectedvalue,manufacturerUnique.get(i)));
                        System.out.println("manufacturerUnique added:"+manufacturerUnique.get(i));
                    }
                    System.out.println("related:"+relatedMedicine.size());                    
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (final Exception ex) {
                    Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? I would greatly appreciate any feedback or pointing to a similar problem like this,thanks.

**edit:**

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DBHelper dbHelper=null;

    ExpandableListView expandableListview;
    String selectedvalue="";

    List<String> manufacturerUnique;
    List<String>relatedMedList;
    Map<String,ArrayList<String>>relatedMedicine;
    //ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    BaseExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }
         selectedvalue = extras.getString("selected_data");
        if (selectedvalue != null) {
            TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2SelectedData);
            textView.setText(selectedvalue);
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
        }
        fillData();
        ExpandableListView expandableListview =(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.ExpandablelistSelectedData);
         expandableListAdapter=new CustomAdapterExpandableList(this,manufacturerUnique,relatedMedicine);
       // expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        expandableListview.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    }
    public void fillData(){
        manufacturerUnique=new ArrayList<>();
        relatedMedList=new ArrayList<>();
        relatedMedicine=new HashMap<>();
        dbHelper=new DBHelper(this);
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait","Loading...", false);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    manufacturerUnique=dbHelper.getManfacturerNameListusingBrandOrGenericName(selectedvalue);
                    System.out.println("manufacturerUnique size"+manufacturerUnique.size());
                    for(int i=0;i<manufacturerUnique.size();i++){
                        relatedMedicine.put(manufacturerUnique.get(i),dbHelper.getBrandNameUsingSelectedItemAndmanfacturerName(selectedvalue,manufacturerUnique.get(i)));
                        System.out.println("manufacturerUnique added:"+manufacturerUnique.get(i));
                    }
                    System.out.println("related:"+relatedMedicine.size());
                   // expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// exception


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            expandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




                        }
                    });
                } catch (final Exception ex) {
                    Log.i("---",ex.toString());
                }
            }
        }.start();


    }


}
```

Comment: Most probably your expandable list view is already populated and displayed with 0 data  as your bg process keeps running. When bg process completes, the view is not redrawn. So you need to notify the changes to the expandable list view. There should be notfiyDataSetChanges or similar method. Otherwise you might need to implement your  custom observers.

Comment: @Jimmy i've checked there isno notfiyDataSetChanges() for expandablelistview  . can you please tell me little more about custom observers .

Comment: Instead of ExpandableListAdapater, use BaseExpandableListAdapter which actualy implement ExpandableListAdapter anyway. In this way you do not have to write custom code as this adapter has notfiyDataSetChanged already implemented. You can refer to this source code  https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.java and implement your own if you like, but I don't see any advantange on reinventing the wheel

Comment: @Jimmy tried but no luck, also tried to override notfiyDataSetChanged but still no, it just calls its super which is the same thing you said . but it dont get it why it's showing if I set debug point

Comment: can you show me how did you call that method ? that should be called somewhere in your fillData() after your data is populated.The adapter should be the original one you initialized in onCreate.

Comment: @Jimmy please see the main question ,  make a edit there

Comment: I think you have adapter caching your realtedMedicine map. Can you create a class that holds static map  -`relatedMedicine`  .And populate this static map in your fill data and in getView , get your data from this relatedMedicine static map.